# RBAC nested permissions

Tags: permissions, access-control, rbac

I'm trying to implement the RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) on a website.
The problem is the permission of nested objects.
Suppose we have some projects on the website. Each user can have a role in each project. e.g. user1 has the *admin role* in project1 and the *customer role* in project2.
Admin role, for example, consists of some permissions like Adding subproject, Deleting subproject, etc.
All docs I've read about RBAC, define general permissions like **Add subproject**, but when a user has this permission, it can add subproject for **all projects** not a specific project (here project1).
How can I restrict such permission to a specific project?
One bad solution is to define new permissions for each project. So the permissions will be **Add subproject to project1**, **Delete subproject from project1**, etc. and defining the corresponding roles like **project1 Admin**.
But I don't feel good about this redundancy; while the projects themselves can be added/removed, dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I've got a <s>solution</s> workaround for such a situation.
My problem with granularity was raised because of an extra-large context: where projects themselves are considered to be resources having **independent** permissions. But the problem is that with such permissions, other nested permissions are not independent anymore. (i.e. `create_subproject` permission is depended on `project_access` permission; which breaks granularity.
So the workaround is to define permissions at the project level (assuming the project itself is accessible), and define the tuples of <user, role, project> to specify which user has which roles on each project.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've run into one of the known limitations of RBAC: permissions can only be assigned to user roles (not to resources or operations).

Recently, there has been growing development in permissions services based on Google's [Zanzibar paper](https://research.google/pubs/pub48190/) which describes a more general permissions system that supports describing resources, users, and relationships between them.

In a Zanzibar based system, you would define a resource for Projects, an admin and customer relation for Projects, and then defines tuples to manifest actual relationships representing your data. Thus, you can define <project1, admin, user1> and <project2, customer, user1>, a straightforward way to represent and check granular permissions on resources. This is a conceptual overview but there are concrete services where you can read their implementation specific details as well as try them out.

I stumbled across your post while researching authorization as part of my new job so I'm adding this answer in case others encounter similar challenges. Some resources we've put together than may be useful:

- [What is Zanzibar?](https://authzed.com/blog/what-is-zanzibar/): blog post that gives an overview
- [Playground](https://play.authzed.com): an interactive tool for writing and testing namespaces (there's a pre-written RBAC example you can test as well)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am a RBAC beginner

The way i understood RBAC is that you have Permissions which combine actual Resources and Operations.
In your case: The Resource would be "project1" and the Operation would be "create_subproject", so the Permission would be called "project1.create_subproject", which indicates that you have one permission per Resource, hence the mentioned redundancy.

My proposal to your question is to introduce a ResourceGroup. This is not part of the NIST RBAC Standard though. A ResourceGroup would combine Resources of a common type.
The access check goes through all objects in the ResourceGroup and if it finds your specific Resource it can evaluate the allowed Operations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, my problem is vice versa! I want to separate a resource group (Project) into multiple resources so they can have different permissions...